# Getting a character from specific coordinates in a ncurses window

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

I have to draw up a maze using ncurses and windows , I've gotten the drawing part down but now my character has to move and not be able to go through obstacles. This is what I tried to do with the movement to check for obstacles (which are represented with 'O' in this case)

```
while((ch = getch()) != KEY_F(1))
{   switch(ch)
    {   case KEY_UP:
            move_x -= 1;
                            if(move_x != 0){
                                wmove(my_win, move_x, move_y);
                                wrefresh(my_win);
                            }
                            else{
                                move_x +=1;
                                wmove(my_win, move_x, move_y);
                                wrefresh(my_win);
                            }
            break;
        case KEY_DOWN:
            move_x += 1;
                            if(move_x != height-1 && mvwinch(my_win, move_y, move_x)!='O'){
                                wmove(my_win, move_x, move_y);
                                wrefresh(my_win);
                            }
                            else{
                                move_x -=1;
                                wmove(my_win, move_x, move_y);
                                wrefresh(my_win);
                            }
            break;
        case KEY_LEFT:
            move_y -= 1;
                            if(move_y != 0 && mvwinch(my_win, move_y, move_x)!='O'){
                                wmove(my_win, move_x, move_y);
                                wrefresh(my_win);
                            }
                            else{
                                move_y +=1;
                                wmove(my_win, move_x, move_y);
                                wrefresh(my_win);
                            }

            break;
        case KEY_RIGHT:
            move_y += 1;
                            if(move_y != width-1 && mvwinch(my_win, move_y, move_x)!='O'){
                                wmove(my_win, move_x, move_y);
                                wrefresh(my_win);
                            }
                            else{
                                move_y -=1;
                                wmove(my_win, move_x, move_y && mvwinch(my_win, move_y, move_x)!='O');
                                wrefresh(my_win);
                            }
            break;
```

I think my problem is that i'm not really understanding what mvwinch returns ? And the whole chtype thing.

There might be a few extra refreshes in there but i'm just trying to get it working for now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question specifically? What is the problem with this code? What don't you understand?

Comment: The question specifically is 'how can i check which character is at a certain position inside a window' since this "mvwinch(my_win, move_y, move_x)!='O'" isn't working properly (probably my understand of what mvwinch returns is wrong);

Comment: _"isn't working properly"_ is not a problem description. What is "proper"? And what happens instead?

Comment: isn't working properly as in it's literally not doing anything it just ignores that 'verification' if I add to guess it would be because mvwinch returns a chtype but I have no idea how to declare one of those.

Answer (score 3):

**`chtype`** is an unsigned integer, which can contain both a *character* and video attributes (bold, underline, reverse, blink) as well as color.  That is done by putting those values into specific bits of **`chtype`**.

In ncurses (as in other implementations), the *character* occupies the low-order bits, allowing you to obtain the character simply by *AND*ing with a predefined symbol **`A_CHARTEXT`**:

```
int ch = mvwinch(my_win, move_y, move_x) & A_CHARTEXT;
```

With ncurses, **`A_CHARTEXT`** is eight bits (value 255).  Other implementations do not necessarily use that size (16-bits was used by more than one Unix vendor).  There is a section discussing the values in the ncurses manual page that discusses [curses attributes](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_attr.3x.html#h2-HISTORY).